# Unmarshalling error after obfuscation

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, obfuscation, unmarshalling

I am getting following exception whenever I try to unmarshal xml file with my obfuscated jar file.

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"XCaliberMessage"). Expected elements are (none)
```

If jar file is not obfuscated then it works fine.

Here is My code:

```
fileName = "/xcalSmartChk/test-job.xml";
                File f = new File(fileName);
                JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(UploadTestResultXml.class);
                Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();


                UploadTestResultXml xMssg = (UploadTestResultXml) u.unmarshal(f);
                Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
                m.marshal(xMssg, bodyElement);
```

Note: I have also keep classes related to this function while obfuscating.

Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: obfuscation changes the names of your classes and packages. this might be creating problems

Comment: As I said, I kept name of that classes as it is. But still problem occur.

Comment: provide some examples how you used the Jaxb annotations. especially the root element

Comment: XML file:
<XCaliberMessage><FunctionName>XCaliberGetDevicePartNo</FunctionName><IMEI>22222222223</IMEI><SN/></XCaliberMessage>

Answer (score -1):

Add following entry in your RGS file to preserve annotations

```
.option Annotations
```